# How can I annotate the lifetimes for this Rust/Calloop callback code?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am trying to write a function that adds a callback function to [Calloop's](https://docs.rs/calloop/0.7.1/calloop/index.html) event loop. The code works fine if it is simply pasted into a function where the function parameters are all in scope and on the stack. Pulling it out into a function results in lifetime problems.

This is as much as I could simplify the code before having to get into Calloop's internals (which are a bit beyond me as a beginner):

```rust
use calloop::{Interest, Mode, generic::Generic, LoopHandle};
use std::os::unix::io::RawFd;

fn check_function<F, T>(
    handle: &mut LoopHandle<T>,
    fd: RawFd,
    callback: F,
)
where
    F: FnMut(calloop::Readiness, &mut calloop::generic::Fd, &mut T) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
{
    let event_source = Generic::from_fd(fd, Interest::READ, Mode::Edge);

    handle.insert_source(
        event_source,
        callback,
    ).ok();
}
```

Compiling this results in:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
  --> src/test.rs:14:12
   |
4  | fn check_function<F, T>(
   |                   - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `F: 'a`
...
14 |     handle.insert_source(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: the parameter type `F` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the function body at 4:1...
  --> src/test.rs:4:1
   |
4  | / fn check_function<F, T>(
5  | |     handle: &mut LoopHandle<T>,
6  | |     fd: RawFd,
7  | |     callback: F,
8  | | )
9  | | where
10 | |     F: FnMut(calloop::Readiness, &mut calloop::generic::Fd, &mut T) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
   | |_________________________________________________________________________________________________^
note: ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/test.rs:14:12
   |
14 |     handle.insert_source(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since it works when everything is on the stack, I figure I need to tell it that everything has the same (or compatible) lifetimes:

```rust
fn check_function<'a, F, T>(
    handle: &mut LoopHandle<T>,
    fd: RawFd,
    callback: F,
)
where
    T: 'a,
    F: FnMut(calloop::Readiness, &mut calloop::generic::Fd, &mut T) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> + 'a
```

But rustc tells me to add *another* lifetime:

```
error[E0311]: the parameter type `F` may not live long enough
  --> src/test.rs:15:12
   |
4  | fn check_function<'a, F, T>(
   |                       - help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `F: 'b`
...
15 |     handle.insert_source(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: the parameter type `F` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #2 defined on the function body at 4:1...
  --> src/test.rs:4:1
   |
4  | / fn check_function<'a, F, T>(
5  | |     handle: &mut LoopHandle<T>,
6  | |     fd: RawFd,
7  | |     callback: F,
...  |
10 | |     T: 'a,
11 | |     F: FnMut(calloop::Readiness, &mut calloop::generic::Fd, &mut T) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> + 'a
   | |______________________________________________________________________________________________________^
note: ...so that the type `F` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/test.rs:15:12
   |
15 |     handle.insert_source(
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This seems like a rather slow way to learn the alphabet. Rather than just throw lifetime annotations around until it works, I'd really like to understand *how I can tell rustc that these lifetimes are all compatible*. Secondary to that:

- what is "anonymous lifetime #2"?
- is `check_function<'a, F: 'a, ...>` equivalent to `check_function<'a, F, ...> where F: ... + 'a`?

Comment: I *think* I figured out that "anonymous lifetime #2" is the second closure parameter ie. `&'a mut calloop::generic::Fd` - but I'm not 100% sure, because (a) it's not on line 4, but maybe it's referring to the start of the function definition, and (b) it still doesn't compile with such an annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rustc wasn't being very helpful with this, but what I found is that `LoopHandle` is parametrized with a lifetime, and since the handle takes ownership of the passed in `FnMut` the `FnMut` must outlive the `LoopHandle`. Once that's figured out, annotating the correct lifetime is pretty easy:

```rust
use calloop::{
    generic::{Fd, Generic},
    Interest, LoopHandle, Mode,
};
use std::io::Result;
use std::os::unix::io::RawFd;
fn check_function<'a: 'b, 'b, F, T>(handle: &mut LoopHandle<'b, T>, fd: RawFd, callback: F)
where
    F: 'a + FnMut(calloop::Readiness, &mut Fd, &mut T) -> Result<()>,
{
    let event_source = Generic::from_fd(fd, Interest::READ, Mode::Edge);

    handle.insert_source(event_source, callback).ok();
}
```

Comment: I've never seen the syntax `'a: 'b` before! I assume that means `'a` is a subtype of `'b` ie. `'a` outlives `'b`?

Comment: @detly Almost- it means `'a` must live at least as long as `'b`. `'a` and `'b` can be the same.